# From nested dict to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary where each key is a table name and the corresponding values are the column header and the row values. I would to obtain a csv of each table. I'd prefer one csv with all table if it is possible, but it is not mandatory because I could save a csv per table.

The `dict` appears as

```py
{
    'Numero contatti creati': [
        ['brand', 'count', 'countLastMonth'],
        ['app IO', '1', '0', 'pagoPA', '2', '0']
    ],
    'Risposte totali': [
        ['Field', 'Responses'],
        ['Data registrata', '2']
    ],
    ...
}
```

where each dictionary key is a table name and each value is a table. For example in the first table named `'Numero contatti creati'`, I have three columns: `brand`, `count`, and `countastMonth`. In each key the first value is always the title of the columns and the second one is the data.
I tried to do it in the following way

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(data['Numero contatti creati'][1:]).reshape(-1,3), columns= (data['Numero contatti creati'][0])).to_csv()
```

where 3 is the number of columns. If I write in this way I cannot load in the property way the csv generated, because of the following error:

```py
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: ',brand,count,countLastMonth\r\n0,app IO,1,0\r\n1,pagoPA,2,0\r\n'
```

How I could fix it?

Comment: Can you share an example of the desired output?

Comment: Your error looks like parts of your dictionary are just strings, not lists. E.g. here `',brand,count,countLastMonth\r\n0,app` there's no closing `]` after `countLastMonth` but a `\r\n`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for your case. You can add the path in the last line to save each dataset as a separate csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for table_name, table_data in data.items():
    formatted_list = []
    
    row_data = table_data[1]
    cols = table_data[0]
    row_data_len = len(row_data)
    num_cols = len(cols)

    for row_index in range(0, row_data_len, num_cols):
        formatted_list.append(row_data[row_index:row_index+num_cols])

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=formatted_list, columns=cols)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: `for table_name, (cols, row_data)`

Comment: And I see no reason to use `pandas` here, built-in `csv` more then enough to write rows into file. *And remove `numpy` import*.